# How to add ALL ROWS in fflib selector class

Tags: apex, fflib

I need to get delete records in SOQL query so i have used ALL ROWS in the end of the SOQL in SOQL its working fine but I need to add in fflib selector class Im getting error

```
public List<AccountTeamMember> selectByDeletedId( Set<Id> ids)
{
      
      return Database.query(
            newQueryFactory()
                    .selectField('Id')
                    .selectField('AccountId')
                    .selectField('AccountAccessLevel')
                    .selectField('TeamMemberRole')
                    .selectField('UserId')
                    .selectField('Account.RecordTypeId')
                    .selectField('Account.ShippingCountry')
                    .setCondition('Id IN:ids AND IsDeleted = TRUE All Rows' ) 
                    
                    .toSOQL()
    );
}
```

Im getting error like this

> System.QueryException: unexpected token: All Rows

can anyone help me in this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like there is no [fflib](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common/blob/master/sfdx-source/apex-common/main/classes/fflib_QueryFactory.cls) solution for it. Append the `ALL ROWS` string at the end of a built query string.

```
public List<AccountTeamMember> selectByDeletedId( Set<Id> ids)
    {
          
          return Database.query(
                newQueryFactory()
                        .selectField('Id')
                        .selectField('AccountId')
                        .selectField('AccountAccessLevel')
                        .selectField('TeamMemberRole')
                        .selectField('UserId')
                        .selectField('Account.RecordTypeId')
                        .selectField('Account.ShippingCountry')
                        .setCondition('Id IN:ids AND IsDeleted = TRUE') 
                        .toSOQL()
                        + ' ALL ROWS';
        );

}
```

---

Why not extend your `fflib_QueryFactory` class with this missing functionality?

```
public class fflib_QueryFactory{
    private Boolean allRows = false;
...
    public fflib_QueryFactory setAllRows(Boolean allRows){
        this.allRows = allRows;
        return this;
    }


    public String toSOQL(){
        String result = 'SELECT ';
        //if no fields have been added, just add the Id field so that the query or subquery will not just fail
        if (fields.size() == 0){
            if (enforceFLS) fflib_SecurityUtils.checkFieldIsReadable(table, 'Id');
            result += 'Id';
        }else {
            List<String> fieldsToQuery = new List<String>(fields);
        
            if(sortSelectFields){
                fieldsToQuery.sort(); 
            }   
        
            result += String.join(fieldsToQuery,', ');
        }
        
        if(subselectQueryMap != null && !subselectQueryMap.isEmpty()){
            for (fflib_QueryFactory childRow : subselectQueryMap.values()){
                result += ', (' + childRow.toSOQL() + ') ';
            }   
        }
        result += ' FROM ' + (relationship != null ? relationship.getRelationshipName() : table.getDescribe().getName());
        if(conditionExpression != null)
            result += ' WHERE '+conditionExpression;

        if(order.size() > 0){
            result += ' ORDER BY ';
            for(Ordering o:order)
                result += o.toSOQL() +', ';
            result = result.substring(0,result.length()-2);
        }
    
        if(limitCount != null)
            result += ' LIMIT '+limitCount;

        if(offsetCount != null)
            result += ' OFFSET '+offsetCount;

        if(allRows)
            result += ' ALL ROWS';

        return result;
    }
...
}
```

and the usage of it:

```
public List<AccountTeamMember> selectByDeletedId( Set<Id> ids)
    {
          
          return Database.query(
                newQueryFactory()
                        .selectField('Id')
                        .selectField('AccountId')
                        .selectField('AccountAccessLevel')
                        .selectField('TeamMemberRole')
                        .selectField('UserId')
                        .selectField('Account.RecordTypeId')
                        .selectField('Account.ShippingCountry')
                        .setCondition('Id IN:ids AND IsDeleted = TRUE') 
                        .setAllRows(true)
                        .toSOQL();
        );

}
```